# SonarQube Install - startsonar.bat fails

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

SonarQube 6.0 Installation

- No plugins currently installed
- Presently working through what appears to be connect string problem

In a command prompt, running as Administrator, I enter

StartSonar

This fails with rather cryptic output to the Command Prompt window.  The following is what I believe is the relevant excerpt from the sonar.log file:

```
2016.08.11 12:23:29 INFO  web[o.sonar.db.Database] Create JDBC data source for jdbc:sqlserver://localhost/DevOps;databaseName=sonar
2016.08.11 12:23:43 ERROR web[o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/sonar]] Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformServletContextListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not connect to database. Please check connectivity and settings (see the properties prefixed by 'sonar.jdbc.').
    at org.sonar.db.DefaultDatabase.checkConnection(DefaultDatabase.java:104) ~[sonar-db-6.0.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.db.DefaultDatabase.start(DefaultDatabase.java:71) ~[sonar-db-6.0.jar:na]
```

Relevant excerpt from .config file:

```
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost/DevOps:1433;databaseName=sonar
sonar.jdbc.username=SonarQube
sonar.jdbc.password=PassWord1234
```

**Finally, victory is mine!**  To be fair, I looked at the .config file from TeamCity.  *Thanks JetBrains!*

The correct entries from the .config file (Note backslash / escape characters!):

```
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc\:sqlserver\://localhost\\DevOps\:1433;databaseName\=Sonar
sonar.jdbc.username=SonarQube
sonar.jdbc.password=PassWord1234
```

Comment: Take a look at $SONARQUBE_HOME/logs/sonar.log and [edit] your question to add any errors there, pls.

Comment: Which plugins (and version) did you install?